# what is Null used for?

Tags: scala

I have done abit of research on this and the only information I can get is that Scala.Null exists solely for backward compatibility with Java. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

See the [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Null):

> Null is - together with scala.Nothing - at the bottom of the Scala type hierarchy.
>
> Null is a subtype of all reference types; its only instance is the null reference. Since Null is not a subtype of value types, null is not a member of any such type. For instance, it is not possible to assign null to a variable of type scala.Int.